# How to specify on which Core Data Configuration to create a new record using CloudKit

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

Let's suppose I have an app using CloudKit + Core Data sync.

My use case is:

- provide the same read only data to all my users (a kind of baseline data that can be modified **only by the admin**)
- each user will be able to write it's private data.

For doing that:

My entities are: "**Entity1**" and "**Entity2**".

My Configurations are: "**Config1**" and "**Config2**". Both have **entity1** and **entity2** and both are "**usedWithCloudKit**".

In my coreDataStack, I have 2 descriptions. The first one is for Config1 and the second one is for Config2 and has "`databaseScope = .public`"

By doing this, if the user saves something into the app, the record will appear in the private db.

If I manually add something to the public DB via iCloud Dashboard, it will be fetched by the user.

So far so good.

Now, if I'm an admin, how can I specify that my SAVE will go to the public DB and not the private one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this via:

```
assign(_ object: Any, to store: NSPersistentStore)
```